# How do I print the user's input (Array) in java?

Tags: java, arrays

The output keeps showing **0**, how can I change it? I want to print the user's array however my output takes the users input and print **0**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    int userArray[] = new int [50];

    Scanner lagoScan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Input Column of Array: ");
    int colInput = lagoScan.nextInt();

    for(i=1; i<= colInput; i++) {
        userArray [i] = lagoScan.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(userArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: in `colInput ` you just have the number of columns. You are not accepting the data that you want to save. Accept the data, put it in array and then print output inside the for loop

Comment: What do you think the value of `i` is in `System.out.println(userArray[i]);`? Answer: It is greater than the last index that you have entered data for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop currently starts at the second index of the array, and you print the last index past `colInput+1` (which you never set) so you get the default value of 0. Also, instead of hardcoding the length of `50` you should use the user provided value to declare the array. Finally, use [`Arrays.toString(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-int:A-) to print the entire array (and limit variable scope when possible). Like,

```
int colInput = lagoScan.nextInt(); 
int[] userArray = new int[colInput];
for (int i = 0; i < colInput; i++) {
    userArray[i] = lagoScan.nextInt();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

this code asks the user to enter 3 numbers and then print it out, I still don't know how to make it print all the numbers at once not individual, I think another for statement. I hope it helps.
+don't mind the "enter the date.."

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
     Scanner cs= new Scanner(System.in);
    
     int[] date= new int[3];
    
     System.out.println("Enter the date for today: ");
     
    
     for(int i=0;i<=2;i++){
         
     date[i]=cs.nextInt(); 


     System.out.println(date[i]);
     
     }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

There is a bug in the code if I understand your intention properly.

`System.out.println(userArray[i]);` needs to be inside the `for` loop reading the input from the `Scanner` and copying it to your `userArray`.

Since your `i` variable's scope exists outside the loop, it points to the end of scanned inputs i.e. index of `userArray` where nothing has been stored yet, it gives the default value as 0.

You're fortunate that this does not raise a fault/exception first (since you have initialized it to a fixed capacity of 50 and the scanned input size might have been less than 50 in your tests). If your scanned input were larger, you could have been accessing out-of-bounds in your `userArray` after the loop was done modifying `i`.

Comment: Java does not segmentation fault ("not usually anyway"). OP is lucky to not receive an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Thanks, @ElliottFrisch for the correction (and edited the answer). I was slightly out of touch with Java while writing this but aimed at explaining the generic bug.

Comment: Thank for the help! I realize it now

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner lagoScan = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Input Number of Elements in Array: ");
            int colInput = lagoScan.nextInt();    
            int userArray[] = new int [colInput];

                for(int i=0; i< colInput; i++) {
                System.out.print("Input "+i+"th Element:");
                 userArray [i] = lagoScan.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(userArray));
        }
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat how about now !!